# TForm Transparency when the forms parent is set to a non-nil value

Tags: delphi

If you create a form on the fly and set its parent to the parent form why does transparency not work.  Transparency is ok if the parent is nil.  I was hoping to create a non-rectangular component using transparency rather than regions.

I see that if the parent forms transparency is on and its value is set to the same value as the child then it sort of works but what you see is what is under the parent form not what is on the parent form.

Thanks

```
unit Unit66;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TNewForm = class(TForm)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TCOmponent); override;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;

  TForm66 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    cbSetParent: TCheckBox;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Nf: TNewForm;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form66: TForm66;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TNewForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited CreateNew(AOwner);
  Self.Color := $1;
  Paint;
end;

procedure TNewForm.Paint;
begin
  inherited Paint;
  Self.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
  Self.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  Self.Canvas.RoundRect(30, 30, Self.ClientWidth - 30, Self.ClientHeight - 30, 20, 20);
  Self.TransparentColorValue := $1;
  Self.TransparentColor := True;
end;

procedure TForm66.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(Nf) then
    Nf.Free;

  Nf := TNewForm.Create(Self);

  if CbSetParent.Checked then
    Nf.Parent := Self
  else
    Nf.Parent := nil;

  Nf.Visible := True;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Why do you want to set the `Parent` of the new form? Forms usually don't have a parent, but only an owner - you already specify that in `TNewForm.Create(Self)`.

Comment: I think transparency is implemented at the top level window. Won't work for children. If you want to cut out a hole in your window, you'll need to use a region. BTW, Free includes a nil check. Not idiomatic to repeat it.

Comment: I was going to base the component on a form (hence setting the parent) because transparency was an easy option but it looks like its top level only  .  It looks like its going to have to be a region..  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Peter `TForm.TransparentColorValue` is implemented using the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style, which is supported for child windows only in Windows 8 and later. Also, setting the `TransparentColorValue` inside an overriden `Paint()` method is just plain wrong, do it in the constructor instead. And `$1` is an odd color to use for transparency, why not use something more like `clFuschia` instead?

Comment: Remy - Thanks for the comments.  Agreed setting the transparentcolourvalue inside the paint is in the wrong place.  I would have thought that the transparentcolourvalue should be one that it unlikely to be used for anything else.  Granted $1 is an odd value but given that it signifies transparency it does not really matter.  Having done some reading and seen the comments from people saying that regions are no longer necessary this is clearly wrong.  Transparency only works on a whole from and will not be of any use in a component that will have a parent which is a form.